# How to iterate rows in turn in SQLite on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

EDIT ____________________________________________

How my code currently looks, with the same cannot find symbol error.

CompleteSurveyActivity.java

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Dialog;

public class CompleteSurveyActivity extends DashBoardAppActivity
{

Button btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3;
LoginDataBaseAdapter DataBaseLink;
EditText editNameComplete;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message);

    DataBaseLink = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(CompleteSurveyActivity.this);
    DataBaseLink.open();



    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionnn);
    tv.setText(DataBaseLink.getAllQuestions.get(index));

    editNameComplete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);


    //tv.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getQuestion());



    //get refs of buttons
    btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer1.setText(DataBaseLink.getAnswer1());
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer2);
    btnAnswer2.setText(DataBaseLink.getAnswer2());
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer3);
    btnAnswer3.setText(DataBaseLink.getAnswer3());
}


public void answer1(View V) {

    final  EditText editNameComplete=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNameComplete);

    // Set On ClickListener
    Button btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stud

            String name = editNameComplete.getText().toString();
            DataBaseLink.insertResponse(DataBaseLink.getQuestion(), name, DataBaseLink.getAnswer1());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Logged ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            index++;
        }
    });

}

public void answer2(View V) {

    // Set On ClickListener
    Button btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stud

            String name = editNameComplete.getText().toString();
            DataBaseLink.insertResponse(DataBaseLink.getQuestion(), name, DataBaseLink.getAnswer2  ());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Logged ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            index++;
        }
    });

}

public void answer3(View V) {

    // Set On ClickListener
    Button btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stud

            String name = editNameComplete.getText().toString();
            DataBaseLink.insertResponse(DataBaseLink.getQuestion(), name, DataBaseLink.getAnswer3());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Logged ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            index++;
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    DataBaseLink.close();
}


}
```

And my database adapter

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter
{
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
        "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table "+"QUESTIONS"+
        "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement," + "QUESTION  text,ANSWER1 text,ANSWER2 text,ANSWER3 text);  ";
static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "create table "+"RESPONSE"+
        "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement," + "QUESTION  text,USER text, ANSWER int); ";
// Variable to hold the database instance
public  SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;


public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
{
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close()
{
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
{
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//new try



public void insertQuestion(String question, String answerOne, String answerTwo, String answerThree) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("QUESTION", question);
    newValues.put("ANSWER1", answerOne);
    newValues.put("ANSWER2", answerTwo);
    newValues.put("ANSWER3", answerThree);
    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("QUESTIONS", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void insertResponse(String question, String user, String answer) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    //assign values for each row
    newValues.put("QUESTION", question);
    newValues.put("USER", user);
    newValues.put("ANSWER", answer);
    //insert
    db.insert("RESPONSE", null, newValues);
}

   /** public String getResponse()
       {
       Cursor cursor=db.query("RESPONSE", null, null, null, null, null,    null);
       if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Question not exist
       {
        cursor.close();
        return "NO RESPONSES";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String response= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("QUESTION","USER","ANSWER"));
    cursor.close();
    return response;
}
*/

public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
{
    //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
    String where="USERNAME=?";
    int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
    // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
}
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

public String getQuestion()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("QUESTIONS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Question not exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NO QUESTIONS";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String question= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("QUESTION"));
    cursor.close();
    return question;
}

public List<String> getAllQuestions(){
    List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT QUESTION FROM QUESTIONS ";
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        questions.add(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    cursor.close();


    return questions;

}

public String getAnswer1()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("QUESTIONS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Question doesnt exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NO QUESTIONS";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String answer1= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ANSWER1"));
    cursor.close();
    return answer1;
}
public String getAnswer2()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("QUESTIONS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Question doesnt exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NO QUESTIONS";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String answer2= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ANSWER2"));
    cursor.close();
    return answer2;
}
public String getAnswer3()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("QUESTIONS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Question doesnt exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NO QUESTIONS";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String answer3= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ANSWER3"));
    cursor.close();
    return answer3;
}


public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
{
    // Define the updated row content.
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

    String where="USERNAME = ?";
    db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}
```

I still do not understand why the code is not recognising the mothod within the database class.

Comment: What errors to you get?  Are they compiler errors, or exceptions at runtime?

Comment: My compiler says "cannot resolve symbol getAllQuestions".

Answer (score 0):

To get all questions from your database you should use this code:

```
    public List<String> getAllQuestions(){
    List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT questions FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String question;
            question = cursor.getString(0);
            // Adding question to list
            questions.add(question);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return questions;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Your final code in CompleteSurveyActivity.java will be:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Dialog;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CompleteSurveyActivity extends DashBoardAppActivity
{

Button btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3;
LoginDataBaseAdapter db;
EditText editNameComplete;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message);

    db = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(CompleteSurveyActivity.this);
    db.open();

    editNameComplete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionnn);
    tv.setText(db.getAllQuestions.get(index));

    //get refs of buttons
    btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer1.setText(db.getAnswer1());
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer2);
    btnAnswer2.setText(db.getAnswer2());
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer3);
    btnAnswer3.setText(db.getAnswer3());
    }
```

Comment: Then with each click of an answer simply read the next value within the array list?

Comment: @Dave95 Yes, like this: `getAllQuestions.get(index);` where index is an int which represents the index of the question inside the Array.

Comment: @Dave95 I have edit my answer. Can you check if it works, please?

Comment: No sadly not, i already have a DataBaseAdapter open with  LoginDataBaseAdapter  = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(CompleteSurveyActivity.this);. Therefor i cannot insert the code you say.

Comment: @Dave95 Please avoid naming `LoginDataBaseAdapter LoginDataBaseAdapter;` at the beginning. Name it something else instead. This is why it sais: `cannot resolve symbol getAllQuestions`

Comment: Yeah i'm a little confused by this, as there seems to be a million things named this. At the first part if i change it to be named "DatabaseLink" instead, which other instances of LoginDataBaseAdapter within this class need to mirror this and not continue to say "LoginDataBaseAdapter"?

Comment: @Dave95 in my last edit I have writed how your CompleteSurveyActivity.java must be(without answer1,answer2,answer3 etc). Please, check this out.The actuall problem is the naming.

Comment: I have named everything exactly how you say and i still have same error. I do not understand why?

Comment: Is perhaps my method wrong inside of the LoginDataBaseAdapter class?

Comment: @Dave95 Really strange. Try `Log.d("question: ", question);` after `questions.add(question);` and check your Logcat if the answers are printed out.

Comment: I can't compile to test this. My syntax is different from yours slightly in the getAllQuestions() method. Is this a cause? Simply because of how the class is set up.

Comment: @Dave95 I made some tests on my own.First of all, I used getAllQuestions method as you use it and it returned all results from all rows with the same column(like questions from question). Also, I can get AllQuestions and use them from another class successfully with your code being used in CompleteSurveyActivity.java(`DataBaseLink.getAllQuestions.get(index)`). This means that both the method and retrieving questions are correct. Sometimes it is just an error with the IDE or something. Please, try restarting your IDE and try again.

Comment: @Dave95 another thing I noticed is that you have to import java.util.ArrayList; and java.util.List; also in your CompleteSurveyActivity.java Import these two use the code you are using in your question and it will work 100%